# Loading javascript asynchronously

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

The code below loads YouTube API asynchronously

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

How does it behave differently from simply having

```
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

on top of the page? What does it actually mean to "asynchronously load" something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load javascript asynchronously, it means the rest of the page can load without blocking. With the `script src` tag, the rest of the page loading will block until the script is finished downloading and runs.